# How to structure requests exception handling and check for 200 response?

Tags: python, python-requests

1. How should I structure the code so I won't get this error:
   `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`.
2. If I want to ensure I get a 200 response before returning `r.json()`, where should I place this code — inside or outside the `try` block?

   ```
   if r.status_code == requests.code['ok']
   ```

My function:

```
def get_req():
    url = 'https://www.example.com/search'
    data = {'p': 'something'}
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, params=data)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
    return r.json()
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way you can get that error.  I see no references to *r* that can occur unless your call to **requests.get()** succeeded and set *r* properly.  Are you sure you're seeing that happen with the code you're showing us?

Why do you want to check for status code 200?  You're already calling **raise_for_status()**, which basically does that.  **raise_for_status()** checks for some other codes that mean **success**, but you probably want your code to treat those as success for your purpose as well.  So I don't think you need to check for 200 explicitly.

So by the time you call **r.json()** and return, that should be what you want to do.

UPDATE: Now that you've removed the **sys.exit()**, you have to do something specific in the error case.  In the comments I've given you the four possibilities I see.  The simplest one would be to declare your method as returning **None** if the request fails.  This returns the least information to the caller, but you are printing an error already, so that might be fine.  For that case, your code would look like this:

```
def get_req():
    url = 'https://www.example.com/search'
    data = {'p': 'something'}
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, params=data)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
        return None
    return r.json()
```

This code is "correct" if you define returning **None** on failure of the request, but throwing an exception in some other cases, as being the expected behavior.  You might want to catch **Exception** instead or as a separate case, if you never want this method to throw an exception.  I don't know if it's possible for **requests.get()** to throw some other exception than **HTTPError**.  Maybe it isn't, in which case this code will never throw an exception as is.  IMO, it's better to assume it can, and deal with that case explicitly.  The code is much more readable that way and does not require future readers to know what exceptions **requests.get()** is able to throw to understand the behavior of this code in all cases.

Comment: You can downvote this answer, but that doesn't make what it says incorrect.  Tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: You're right, it was when I don't want sys.exit(1) when an exception is raised I get the error.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for saying that.  I'm an old timer who has the goals of 1) helping new programmers, and 2) having S.O. be as high quality a resource as possible.  I really don't care about points, especially now that I've gone over 2000 and can edit posts directly to affect #2 above.  I will make any answer a "community answer" for which I don't get any points whenever requested.  I really just want to help.  Towards all of this, I'd really like to help you to get a full and complete understanding of your code.  I'll do anything I can to help.

Comment: Towards #2, I would suggest that you work with either me or @Fozoro to make the accepted answer both 1) really answer your question (which maybe it does), and 2) not leave loose ends that make the sample code less correct than the original.  I'm happy to let Fozoro get the points.  I just want to see the best answer possible.  I have the ability to edit both the answer and the question, but I'd rather you two do that.

Comment: I removed sys.exit(1) from original post but not sure what else I should do

Comment: That's good.  Sys.exit() is never the right thing to do in a larger program.  I expect you know that.  So the question is: what do you want your method to do a) if you get back a non-success response, and b) if you catch some other exception.  Both of these cases will result in you being inside your exception catch right now. - I believe your code is correct as is if you don't catch an exception.

Comment: The more important of these, i think is the non-success behavior.  How do you want to tell the caller that the request failed?   BTW, your code is now able to crash on the last line, since you now DO have the possibility that you will attempt to use 'r', and it hasn't been defined.  That's fine.  This is a work in progress.

Comment: Note that one possible answer is to remove the try/except completely.  Then the caller gets an exception thrown if the request fails.  If the method returns, it will always do so with valid JSON.  You also might want to now re-throw by throwing your own exception so the caller knows just what sort of exception to expect.  You could decide to just return None if the request fails.  Finally, you could return JSON of your own if the request fails that has error information in it.  It's really up to you.  You just want to decide so it's clear to you and others how this method behaves in all cases.

Comment: Thank you sir. Makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

your function should look like this:

```
def get_req():
    url = 'https://www.example.com/search'
    data = {'p': 'something'}
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, params=data)
        r.raise_for_status()
        if r.status_code == requests.code['ok']:
            return r.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(1)
```

hope this helps

Comment: This is a step backwards for this code.  Now the code is able to get back a "success" status code other than '200', and it will return None to the caller instead of returning the JSON that is in the response and that the caller probably wants returned. - this code is also confusing, as there's usually no reason to both call raise_for_status() and also check for 200.  If this IS somehow the desired behavior, a comment should be put in the code explaining why that is being done, because it's unusual.